# Ionic 2 Flipbook like Turn Js

Tags: angular, ionic2, turnjs

I am building an app for viewing deals with Ionic 2.
I want to develop a flipbook which has to display image as a flipbook like in the following link

[turnjs](http://www.turnjs.com/)

I tried to implement this plugin in Ionic 2 app but was not successful. 
My questions are the following

- Is there any plugin available?
- How can I integrage turn js plugin to my Ionic2 app?(Any guidance)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where you able to make progress on this? turnJS claims to be 10K and I noticed it requires jQuery 1.3 or above.  I don't know if you would want to drag that in as well.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-turnjs

check out that link there for an angular based turn.js implementation. If you want to implement it into your application, build it out as you would but import turn js like this.

```
import * as turnJs from '../path/to/turnjs'
```

this will create a `turnJS` object that you can use to access the library, from there you should be able to use whatever you want from turn.js

Comment: Thanks @Caleb Swank. Basically the example is ionic 1 based and I am still new to Ionic, would you kindly give some more guidance to use this plugin in Ionic 2 component and view?

Comment: I still am stuck in this problem. Any help?