# What can I use to create a book effect (turning pages) into an Angular 2 app? turnjs is ok?

Tags: javascript, angular, javascript-framework, turnjs

I am not so into JavaScript and I am very new in **Angular 2** (I came from Java).

I need to create an **Angular 2** webapp that contains something like a book effect (where the user can turn the pages and see the next content).

Something like **turnjs**, this: http://www.turnjs.com/

Am I asking if this **turnjs** is easily integrable into an Angular 2 application or if there is something better\easier to use.

What do you suggest me?

Comment: `$("#flipbook").turn()`... it's a jQuery plugin. So it won't work in Angular. And NO, I know what you're thinking, don't use jQuery and Angular together.

Comment: @JeremyThille Ok !!! So what can I use to obtain an effect like this using Angular 2?

Comment: I don't know, I've never had to make a flipbook with Angular yet :)

Comment: @JeremyThille And using something like this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-turnjs

Comment: I know that turnjs is JQuery but here it seems that it is "embedded" into an Angular object, is it so bad? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195469/ionic-2-flipbook-like-turn-js

Comment: `angular-turnJS` is for AngularJS (aka Angular 1), not for Angular 2+.

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/20things_pageflip/

above site uses javascript for turning pages .. i used for my online diary project works fine